# How to print a double dagger symbol in a SQR report

Tags: peoplesoft, sqr

Is there a way to print a double dagger symbol in SQR language?

I am trying to see if we can use unicode to print the same in a SQR report

Any help in this regard will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Use the unicode function.

```
LET $str = unicode('U+2021')
print $str ()
```